# Generating PWM with a very short pulse width

Tags: microcontroller

I need to generate a 1 to 10 MHz PWM with a 0.5 ns pulse width. I used to create PWMs with STM32 microcontrollers, but it seems a micro is not enough for such task.

Is there a type of IC one can use/control for the purpose? What ways I should look for? I don't know FPGA programming.

Comment: Is that WIDTH or RESOLUTION ? 
What accuracy do you need ?
A simple R.C and fast logic gate can do it.

Comment: 0.5 ns pulse can be generated with a PWM modulator running at 2 GHz. Do you know anything that runs at 2 GHz? Having a 1 MHz PWM with 2 GHz means you only need to have 11 bits counter.

Comment: What is the application for this?

Comment: There are some MCUs with PWM **resolution** in the <200ps realm but getting a pulse that short out of the output pins seems unlikely.

Comment: @jp314 Do you mean like a one-shot multivibrator? I used once to stretch pulsewidth of pulse train. But the freq was kHz level. Are there such one-shot ICs where we can decrease the pulsewidth down to 0.5ns?

Comment: To clarify: is this PWM, or PFM? There's a lot of overlap, yes, but the difference is largely how you use it. For example, PWM is often filtered for its average value, regardless of frequency (but usually with a constant frequency). PFM is sometimes filtered (e.g. when used for a type of FM discriminator), but also used for other purposes such as timing or sampling. In any case, at such short pulse widths, you can't simply wire up a generator; this is the microwave domain, it must be tightly integrated with the load. Application knowledge is critical.

Answer (score 3):

If, for some reason, you choose not to use FPGA resources, you can try and design the pulse generator on your own.

Short pulses are usually generated from the steady driving pulses with a pulse sharpening network which can include a delay line,

[image: delayline]

like that proposed in **[A compact step recovery diode subnanosecond pulse generator](https://elmag.fel.cvut.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/motl_protiva.pdf)** by Pavel Protiva, Jan Mrkvica,Jan Macháč. For your convenience, see the circuit, captured from this article

[image: circuit]

The article gives a detailed description of the circuit operation, including a PCB layout.

[image: layout]

To tune the circuit, you adjust R2 and select the Schottky diode SD biasing current.

To trigger the generator input, they used a TTL square waveform with a repetition frequency of 5 MHz, adding to their report that frequency up to 10 MHz is applicable without noticeable distortion of the shape of the output pulse. They boast FWHM (Full-Width at Half-Maximum) of about 110 ps with a 4 mm delay line. To have a 0.5 ns pulse, you should increase the delay line length to about 18 mm.

[image: driveroutput]

The driver output before the pulse shaper SD-TL-SRD

[image: outputwaveform]

The output waveform of the pulse shaper

Answer (score 0):

To make a 0.5 ns pulse, you'll need to define events that are 500 ps apart (edge rise, edge fall), so a 2 Gbps rate. You might be able to coax an FPGA serdes to throw a pulse like that, using an external trigger generated by an MCU. You could vary the pulse width in 0.5ns increments by altering the symbols you load into the serdes FIFO.

I think it's also possible using specialty ultra-fast logic, like the stuff offered by Hittite (now part of Analog Devices), to construct a delay line + XOR to detect the MCU trigger. This wouldn't be as flexible as the serdes approach I think. Example Hittite part: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc745.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A pure digital domain solution would seem to require a 2 GHz clock. But maybe it can be done using a DAC (or two), resistor, capacitor, comparator type of arrangement. It would be difficult to test and debug without a fast oscilloscope. And maybe some fast function generator or something, too. The basic idea is that you somehow control the voltage ramp rate of a capacitor which, when it reaches some threshold, switches a very fast comparator (like an LVDS line driver or something). Just a sketch of an idea.